# Would it be advisable to upload my Django Project to github?

Tags: django, github

I know that Django websites contain a secret key which is not to be disclosed to anyone. However, I really want to showcase my website on GitHub, as I feel it is nice. Unfortunately, I am worried about the secret key's security, and if it would be safe to upload that website to GitHub where everyone can see.

The website type is a personal portfolio website that showcases my projects and more.

So, would it be okay to upload my entire Django Project to GitHub? The only sensitive information I can think of would be my superuser information, and maybe my database, where I store all my project Models for displaying on the website. Pretty much all I know I need to guard is my superuser information

Comment: This is not a programming question, so not suited to StackOverflow but you can leave the secret key out and document how to generate one for those who will try it. See a few Django projects on GitHub to see how they do it.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know it wasn't a programming question, and I'll keep it in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The django secret key should not be publicly available (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECRET_KEY)

Many sites use an environment variable to set the key.
So your settings file could have something like:

`SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/jpadilla/django-dotenv.

You can set your secret_key inside a `.env` file which you should add to your `.gitignore`. This means it will not be tracked or added to any git commit, hence, won't be shown in Github.